Extremely long inline code in comments overflows right sidebar
It's egregious e.g. when the viewport exceeds the 1180px's boundary, however it acts erraticly at many viewport sizes.
Ubuntu 24.04.1 / Google Chrome 129.0.6668.58. I can't reproduce it on Firefox 130.0.1, so it might be Chrome / Chromium related.
Comment
This also happens on Meta SE, and I can reproduce it only with strings containg a lot of spaces. Comment


I can also reproduce it on Chromium for various window widths, but not on Firefox. Also, since it's an SE bug that should be fixed by the SE developers, I think you should mention it in MSE. I'm not sure if the per site "bug" tags are seen and addressed by the developers.

@BeastOfCaerbannog Thanks, yeah, I actually flagged this for migration a few days ago, but the flag was declined. I had fogot questions tagged bug are seen by staff anyways :|

@kos Did you manage to post anything similar on Meta SE?

@andrew.46 No I deliberately avoided duplicating the post over at MSE because I was reminded that questions tagged bug would still be noticed by staff members (I flagged this for migration and the flag was declined with this explanation, which actually resonated with me, I think that's correct?). Do you think I should duplicate the post over there for some reason?

@kos To tell the truth I was a little perplexed when I saw the idea that the 'bug' attracted any particular attention, I was not aware of this. And in my mind this looked like a question better suited to Meta SE...

@Spevacus Hey, I don't disagree this is a duplicate, but what does closing it mean? I mean, the other question it's a 2 years old question with no answers / no status tags / no nothing. I'm taking it as a wontfix?

@kos We do commonly close duplicate bug reports provided they are... Well, duplicates. It's a somewhat niche issue that (seems to) affect only Chrome-based browser users. I'll go ahead and tag status-review now since... Yeah, it's a problem (that I can reproduce) and given that you've reported it as well this long after its initial report, it's worth looking at.

@Spevacus I mean for sure it can go in the backlog, it just seems like it never made it there (or it left it some time ago) since two years have gone by since the last report. It's absolutely a minor inconvenience / cosmetic issue, granted. I'd only argue "only Chrome / Chromium" users is probably about two thirds of the userbase :P thanks!

@andrew.46 I'll answer you here since I don't have a diamond to comment on the migrated question :) yeah it's fine, they added status-review to the original which has been stale for a couple of years, so migrating did something! About the bug tag thing; it may be one of those "legends" floating around: when my flag got declined I remembered having known the same thing at some point. Eh, who knows shrug

@kos Heyo. Wanted to let you know that staff followed up about this. You pointing this out lead to this getting a proper response, so I figured you should be aware. :)

@Spevacus But I'm using Chrome 129... sigh Well regardless cheers for the heads up! I posted a comment under KyleMit's answer
